# How to use class variable within the class

Tags: python, python-2.7

for instance:

```
class TEST:
    test = 'a'
    def __init__(self, test=TEST.test):
        self.test=test
    def resetTest(self):
        self.test=TEST.test
```

Then I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in TEST
NameError: name 'TEST' is not defined
```

How can I use class variable `test` within the `TEST`class ?

Comment: It works like this: `def __init__(self, test=test):`

Comment: @Harvey: Post that as an answer, it's right.

Comment: Do you want a change to `TEST.test` to also change the default when future instances are created?

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like below

```
class TEST:
    test = 'a'
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def resetTest(self):
        print self.test
        print TEST.test

t = TEST()
t.resetTest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some background in order to fully understand what's happening here.

Remember that a program is just a series of commands telling a machine what to do. Programming languages give us a way to organize and reason about those commands without knowing the machine-specific implementations, but as a result need to be translated before a machine can execute them. Depending on the language, the translation can be done either all at once via a  **compiler** or as needed via an **interpreter**.

[Compiled languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) such as C, Go, or Haskell use **compilers** to translate the entirety of your code beforehand and output new files with all of the translated instructions. This way the compiler, in many cases, resolve out of order references as long as they are eventually defined. [Interpreted languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) (or *scripting* languages) like Python, Bash, or Ruby use **interpreters** (such as the `python` executable) to read code piece by piece and execute each translated piece immediately without looking ahead.

In your example, the `class` declaration is considered one "piece" and won't be registered as a variable accessible by the interpreter until the entire class body has been parsed.

Note that your traceback points to the `__init__` method of `TEST`:

```
def __init__(self, test=TEST.test):
    self.test=test
```

Since you're in the middle of defining the class at this point, the interpreter doesn't know about it yet, thus:

```
NameError: name 'TEST' is not defined
```

TL;DR This only happens because the interpreter is trying to resolve `TEST.test` immediately so it can cache whatever the default is supposed to be for the `test` parameter to the `__init__()` function declaration. So it would be perfectly safe to move the reference inside the function body itself since it won't be called until you create an instance of the class like this:

```
class TEST:
    test = 'a'

    def __init__(self, test=None):
        if test is not None and test != TEST.test:
            self.test = test

    def resetTest(self):
        self.test=TEST.test
```

You could also put the default variable in a superclass:

```
class BaseTEST:
    test = 'a'

class TEST(BaseTEST):

    def __init__(self, test=BaseTEST.test):
        self.test = test

    def resetTest(self):
        self.test = BaseTEST.test
```

Either way it will be ugly and/or you'll have to compromise, so I'd probably go with declaring default values outside of the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways of doing this:

## Just remove the `TEST.`

Instead of:

```
TEST.test
```

Put:

```
test
```

## As an argument in `__init__()`.

```
def __init__(self, test=test):
    self.test = test
...
```

Note that here you can use both, `test` and `self.test`, you probably don't want both, so just don't do `self.test = test`. Or...

---

Although the code you posted is probably just an example, in this case I would just do: `def __init__(self, test='a'): ...` which is what you do in almost every situation.

Answer (score 0):

What's the meaning of the

> self.test＝TEST.test

I think it can not reset member variable... 
And you can change the two "TEST.test" to "a"

Answer (score 0):

Class variables are accessible in local scope (no `TEST.` required) from method definitions, but not method bodies. So, this would be the correct way to write your example:

```
class TEST:
    # even for an example, this should be named something like default_test.
    test = 'a'

    def __init__(self, test=test):   # can see TEST.test without the classname
        self.test=test

    def resetTest(self):
        self.test=TEST.test          # needs the class name to see TEST.test
```

Some testing:

```
In [23]: TEST.test
Out[23]: 'a'

In [24]: t = TEST()

In [25]: t.test, TEST.test
Out[25]: ('a', 'a')

In [26]: t2 = TEST(123)

In [27]: t2.test, TEST.test, t.test
Out[27]: (123, 'a', 'a')

In [28]: t2.resetTest()

In [29]: t2.test, TEST.test, t.test
Out[29]: ('a', 'a', 'a')
```